# Create two tables in sqlite3 database in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I seem to find many tutorials on how to work with two table, but I can't seem to figure out how to create two tables. I am probably missing something very simple.

I want to create a table for my_data_1 and my_data_2. Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3

my_data_1 = [('a',1,'BUY'),('b',2,'SELL'),('c',3,'HOLD')]

my_data_2 = [('a',1,5),('d',6,6),('e',2,7)]

 #I am using :memory: because I want to experiment
 #with the database a lot

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:') 

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE_1
          (stock TEXT, price REAL, recommendation TEXT )''' )

### Something is probably wrong with the following line

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE_2
          (stock TEXT, price REAL, volume REAL )''' )



for ele in my_data_1:
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_1 VALUES(?,?,?)''',ele)

conn.commit()

c.execute('SELECT* FROM MY_TABLE_1')

for entry in c:
    print entry

c.execute('SELECT* FROM MY_TABLE_2')

for entry in c:
    print entry
```

My output is:

```
(u'a', 1.0, u'BUY')
(u'b', 2.0, u'SELL')
(u'c', 3.0, u'HOLD')
```

So I have not created MY_TABLE_2. How should I do this?

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't inserting anything into Table 2

Try this code after you insert into Table 1.

```
for ele in my_data_2:
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_2 VALUES(?,?,?)''',ele)
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple :). Thank You.